# Help understanding a circuit (li-ion charger with 5v step-up)

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, battery-charging, step-up

In the circuit below, as well as in the typical application schematic for the tp4056, bat+ connects directly to bat- with a 10uF capacitor in between.

Why doesn't this connection end up shorting the battery?
[image]

[image]

Second question, how does the voltage step up work when bat- does not connect to that part of the schematic at all?

Should I assume that bat- is connected to the output GND?

Comment: Please indicate where this happens: *bat+ connects directly to bat- with a 10uF capacitor in between*. Please also indicate where you have seen this: *when bat- does not connect to that part of the schematic at all* - I'm asking because your questions do not make sense to me.

Comment: The schematic is drawn such that it is difficult to see how it should work. However, U1 and Q1 are the battery protection circuit that connects bat- to 0V. I don’t understand why you think C4 shorts the battery (unless it has failed)

Comment: Because of the 10uF capacitor in between. It doesn't conduct DC very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1) Why doesn't the capacitor short Bat+ and Bat-?**

You're working with a DC circuit, hence the 10uF capacitor in this case, works as a voltage filter and does not short Bat+ and Bat-. Essentially, it reduces ripple voltage. [Wiki Capacitor Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor-input_filter#:%7E:text=A%20capacitor%2Dinput%20filter%20is,voltage%20components%20of%20the%20output.)

According to an online website:

> When used in a direct current or DC circuit, a capacitor charges up to its supply voltage but blocks the flow of current through it because the dielectric of a capacitor is non-conductive and basically an insulator. [Introduction to capacitors](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_1.html)

**(2) How does the voltage step up work when bat- does not connect to that part of the schematic at all?**

In most circuits, you can assume that all GND are connected with each other, so you have a reference voltage. *Bat- is connected to GND*